# Where can I find the Roblox Material/Terrain textures?

Tags: textures, roblox

The textures shown in this image: Where can I find them? I am making a Roblox game, it's a terrain based mining game, and I want to add an inventory. Where can I find the textures for the terrain to use as icons? I am not allowed to use screenshots. I am looking for the terrain textures that get rendered, not the icons in the terrain editor. Where in Roblox studio are they located?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find them inside of the game files. If you're on windows 10, use cortana to search up "Roblox" inside of your apps, right click it, and then press "show file location". Then you can look into the game files and find the textures. Also, if you want to use these as a icon, you will have to first copy and crop these images into squares and then upload it to roblox as a decal. Then you may insert a decal into your gui and insert the ID of the image.